# SharePoint @ Edit without having edit permissions

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I'm new on the SharePoint world and right now I'm facing a little adversity.

Right now I do have a list that represents a collection of books. I also created a button with JavaScript that will allow the users to order them for a temporary time.

For this matter when the user clicks on the button, it'll change some column values from that list item, such as: the status, order and return date, some counters... I tested with my account and everything was working fine until I remember that I do have the permissions to edit this list. However if it's a end user, he'll receive (correctly since they haven't permission to edit) the "Request failed. Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource" message and won't be able to order the book.

Well, I could give the permission to this users in order to edit the list, but that way they would be able to delete and edit some columns that they aren't suppose to.

Do anyone have any suggestion/solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this type of scenario, I would suggest using more than one list, so you can manage the books and orders separately. Also, create a workflow in SharePoint Designer that starts when an order is created. This workflow will perform the operations that you are doing in JavaScript.

Here's a basic implementation plan:

- Book List - Give users read only permission to this list.
- Book Order List - Give users *Add* permissions to this list. Add a lookup column to the Book List.
- Book Order Workflow - Perform the management of the order and inventory statuses here. [App Steps](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo) can be utilized to run specified actions in the workflow with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks @horinedev !Your suggestion helped me out on this workaround/solution development.